# Sort list of datetime in Python polars dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

I have problems working with datetime

my dataset is like this:

[image]

And **I wish to sort the dates inside the list on every row, and get the first and second datetime, because some rows has more than 2 values. But I can't do it on Polars.**

I'm trying with :

```py
filter_df.filter(
    pl.col("order_purchase_timestamp").arr.sort()
    )
```

but I got this error:

> ComputeError: Filter predicate must be of type Boolean, got: SchemaMisMatch(Owned("Series of dtype: List(Datetime(Microseconds, None)) != Boolean"))

Comment: `filter` is intended to limit the rows you get back so for example you'd do `df.filter(pl.col('customer_unique_id').str.contains('00172711b'))` to get the first row (plus any other rows that contain that substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.with_columns()` context to select & modify columns.

```py
col = pl.col("order_purchase_timestamp")

df.with_columns(
    col.arr.sort(reverse=True).arr.slice(0, 2)
)   #        /                      /
    #      sort by date            take slice [0:2]
```

---

*Solution that follows from the discussion in the comments*

To perform some action under column based on *condition*, you can use `pl.when -> then -> otherwise` construct. `pl.when()` takes some boolean Series (condition). Read more [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/expressions.html#binary-functions-and-modification).

```py
col = pl.col("order_purchase_timestamp")

# duration (difference) between 2 dates (in microseconds)
diff = pl.duration(microseconds=(col.arr.get(0) - col.arr.get(1)))

df.filter(col.arr.lengths() >= 2).with_columns(
    col.arr.sort(reverse=True).arr.slice(0, 2)
).with_columns(
    less_30 = pl.when(diff <= pl.duration(days=30))\
                .then(True).otherwise(False)
)
```

Comment: I don't think they want the filter, I think they just want the `with_columns`.  They seem to be confused about what filter does.

Comment: This solve part of my problem. This filter plus the sort. How I can get this two values and operate with them? I would like to create a new column, If the difference between datestime is less than 30 days indicates True (or 1), else return 0.

Comment: @Andre Luiz Moura - I modified solution according your q-n in comments.

Comment: @Dean MacGregor - Yess, you are right, `filter` came from previous q-n. I dropped it and made full sol-n below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of operating on lists - you could `.explode()` the column.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"letters": [["f", "a", "m"], ["b"], ["e", "d", "c"]]})
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ letters         │
│ ---             │
│ list[str]       │
╞═════════════════╡
│ ["f", "a", "m"] │
│ ["b"]           │
│ ["e", "d", "c"] │
└─────────────────┘
```

`.with_row_count()` can be used as a "group id":

```
df.with_row_count("group").explode("letters").sort("letters")
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌───────┬─────────┐
│ group | letters │
│ ---   | ---     │
│ u32   | str     │
╞═══════╪═════════╡
│ 0     | a       │
│ 1     | b       │
│ 2     | c       │
│ 2     | d       │
│ 2     | e       │
│ 0     | f       │
│ 0     | m       │
└───────┴─────────┘
```

You could then filter based on the group count ("size"):

```
(df.with_row_count("group")
   .explode("letters")
   .sort("letters")
   .filter(pl.count().over("group") > 1))
```

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬─────────┐
│ group | letters │
│ ---   | ---     │
│ u32   | str     │
╞═══════╪═════════╡
│ 0     | a       │
│ 2     | c       │
│ 2     | d       │
│ 2     | e       │
│ 0     | f       │
│ 0     | m       │
└───────┴─────────┘
```

`.groupby().agg()` can be used to recreate the lists.

`.head` / `.limit` to keep only the first `N` results.

```
(df.with_row_count("group")
   .explode("letters")
   .sort("letters")
   .filter(pl.count().over("group") > 1)
   .groupby("group")
   .agg(pl.col("letters").head(2)))
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬────────────┐
│ group | letters    │
│ ---   | ---        │
│ u32   | list[str]  │
╞═══════╪════════════╡
│ 0     | ["a", "f"] │
│ 2     | ["c", "d"] │
└───────┴────────────┘
```